# How to use \phase on MacTeX?

Tags: math-mode

I'm trying to obtain the effect of the `\phase` command as discribed in the [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirror.softwarelivre.ufsc.br/pub/ctan/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) (page 70)

I've added the `amssymb` and `pict2e` packages correctly (no errors on adding packages), but it keeps saying "Undefined control sequence." when I try to compile.

I'm sure I'm missing something very basic. Is there another package to add? Wich one? Or it just does not work on MacTeX?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation suggests `\usepackage{steinmetz}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{steinmetz}
\begin{document}
$\phase{abc}$
\end{document}
```

[image]